# Building a list of letters indexes from a string

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to iterate over the letters of a string and return the indexes of those letters in a list, but I don't want to use loops or enumerate, the below code is a function that I wrote using enumerate. Any ideas on how we can do the same thing without loops or getting to use the enumerate function.Recursion is not allowed as well.
'''

```
def getIndex(word):

    return list(map(lambda t: t[0],enumerate(word)))

print( getIndex("banana"))
#output
#[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
'''
```

Comment: `range(len(word))`?

Comment: @Sayse thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `list`, with a `range` as argument. This `range` here is a range of numbers from 0 to the length of your word (when you only pass one argument into `range`, like we do here, it defaults to the "stop" value, so the length to which the range will run)

```
def getIndex_zero(word):
    return list(range(len(word)))

print(getIndex_one("Banana")) #Prints [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

This code will generate your desired result.

Depending on whether or not you want to use [zero based indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), you can also use the following (To make your list start at 1)

```
def getIndex_one(word):
    return list(range(1, len(word)+1))

print(getIndex_one("Banana")) #Prints [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```